# query to get email , contact name , and number in 1 line of code

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

nullim using Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                         .query(contactUri, projection, null,null,null);  to get the    number of clicked contact. Is it possible to get the email, number and name using this query. at the same time?
can we do it this way? as shown below?

```
                 String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
             String[] projection1 = {Email.DATA};
             String[] projection2 = {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
                 query(contactUri, projection, null,projection1,projection2);
             cursor.moveToFirst();
                 int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
             int column1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);
             int column2= cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
             String number = cursor.getString(column);
             String email1 = cursor.getString(column1);
             String name1 = cursor.getString(column2)
```

is this possible?

Is this correct now?

```
   String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, Email.ADDRESS, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
             query(contactUri, projection, null,null,null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
             int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
         int column1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.ADDRESS);
         int column2= cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
         String number = cursor.getString(column);
         String email1 = cursor.getString(column1);
         String name1 = cursor.getString(column2)


             editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
             editText17 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText17);
             editText3.setText(number); 
             editText17.setText(email1);
```

only the phone number is getting set in the text box
edittext3 and edittext17  both have mobile number? what an i doing wrong?
 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put more than one value in an Array:

```
String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, Email.DATA, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
```

---

All together:

```
String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, Email.DATA, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
int column1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);
int column2= cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) { // Check if data exists
     String number = cursor.getString(column);
     String email1 = cursor.getString(column1);
     String name1 = cursor.getString(column2)
}
```

Comment: only the phone number is getting set in the text box edittext3 and edittext17 both have mobile number? what an i doing wrong? thank you

Comment: im getting name and number but in the place of email the number ids coming again :(

Comment: Try `Email.ADDRESS` instead of `Email.DATA`.

Comment: not working :( again number is coming. Actually Email.ADDRESS should give email address i dont no y its not working?

Comment: Uri contactUri = data.getData();

Comment: finally got using Email.CONTENT_URI, but now im getting only email